# Grant select permission on all database to a user-defined server role

Tags: sql-server

Can I grant select permission on all database to a user-defined role?
I create a user-defined server role, and add logins as members of it.
I want these logins can view all databases and have select permission on all databases.
how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_addrolemember db_datareader, <User-Defined Role>;
```

This is equivalent to granting SELECT on all tables in the DB.

Comment: sorry,I mean a user-defined server role,not a database role

Comment: Why would you not use db_datareader as a part of any group or role you want to grant this access to?  The role exists to do exactly what you are asking for.